# How are commits counted by the GitHub contributions graph?

Tags: git, github

How are contributions in the GitHub Contributions graph on my profile counted? (The one with the green dots.) Does whether a commit is counted or not depend on the username in the commit, or the email associated with it?

Please provide details. Is there any way I can associate commits with my username but change my email and still have the green dots appear?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GitHub has an article about this on their site. See *[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)* Regarding commits, the article says:

> ### Commits
>
> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of
>   the following conditions:
>
> - The commits were made within the past year.
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch (usually master)
>   - In the gh-pages branch (for repositories with Project Pages sites)
>
> In addition, at least one of the following must be true:
>
> - You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> - You have forked the repository.
> - You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
> - You have starred the repository.

You can associate multiple email addresses with your GitHub account from your [email settings page](https://github.com/settings/emails).

Comment: What happens to contributions in the github graph after a repo(mine, for example) is deleted? Do the contributions remain there like a ghost or they'll disappear?

Comment: If I commit to a branch that is not the default, does that commit not count?

Comment: @Flimtix that's correct. Though if that commit on a non-default branch ever gets merged onto the default branch, then your commit will count.

Comment: @Patrick What date is entered on the graph? (merge or commit date)

Comment: @Flimtix, the author date is used to calculate when a commit was made on your profile page. The author is usually the same as the commit date, but can differ if someone changes the commit date (e.g. amend, force push, etc). https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/troubleshooting-commits-on-your-timeline

Comment: Adding here that for organizational repos, only main/master commits are counted. So after a merge, all commits that you did (e.g. your feature brach) will appear on your dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure setting your email in local configuration.

```
git config --global user.name "kimcrab"
git config --global user.email "kimcrab89@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

For more information, see [Common reasons that contributions are not counted](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted):

1. Commit was made less than 24 hours ago;
2. Your local Git commit email isn't connected to your account;
3. Commit was not made in the default or gh-pages branch;
4. Commit was made in a fork;