# my contributions not showing up on my profile. Activity overview graph not showing all contribution on graph

Tags: github, github-pages

Activity overview graph not showing all contribution to the graph. How can I saw all the contribution?  Activity graph is below.

[image: screnshot of contributions chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting "**Private contributions**" on Contribution settings.

[image: contribution settings]

And also you may want to know how GitHub counts the contributions.

- [How are commits counted by the GitHub contributions graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296681/how-are-commits-counted-by-the-github-contributions-graph)
- [Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)

Comment: I change email and user name in local configuration, now its work.
                                                                                                                                                                           
git config --global user.name "kimcrab"
git config --global user.email "kimcrab89@gmail.com"