# Why is the code being pushed by myself on git show up as from somebody else?

Tags: git, github

I have been seeing this weird problem on git wherein I push a certain piece of code from my github account and it shows up as being pushed by my colleague. Git specifically asks for my credentials so I know it is my account, yet all commits are made from this other account. I once did login from his account temporarily but there were no default settings set up on my system. I can't wrap my head around why it might be happening. Do tell ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are commits counted by the GitHub contributions graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296681/how-are-commits-counted-by-the-github-contributions-graph)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that when you borrowed your colleague's credentials that one time, your Git tool cached them, and since then has been reusing them.  Look into `git config` to see how to manually set your username from the bash:

```
git config --global user.name "Shorya Sharma"
```

Then confirm that the settings are sticking:

```
git config --global user.name
```

Comment: Yeah , thanks the global username was set as my colleague's . I have changed it now .Cheers

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)