# My Git Commits not showing on my Git hub graph in my profile

Tags: git, github

i have been using github for some time, right now am wondering why i only see a few commits made. Example, this week i have committed everyday but i have only seen one commit on the git graph. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are commits counted by the GitHub contributions graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296681/how-are-commits-counted-by-the-github-contributions-graph)

Comment: no it doesn't, actually i have not forked the repo, i haven't opened any pull requests, i haven't starred the project

Comment: Just a control question, you've pushed to github?

Comment: Verify email in your commits: `git log --format=fuller`. Must be the same as you've configured at Github.

Comment: this worked well