# I can't see my contributions on github after rebasing

Tags: git, github

Let's say I'm working on some feature.

day1: I worked on it and create a PR with first commit.

day2: I continue working and add 1 more commit to PR

day3: I finished my work, add 1 more commit and do rebasingand forse pushed and merge my PR.

In contribution graph on github I see only 2 contributions: day1 and day3. It looks like I don't push anything in day2. I guess that it's due to the rebasing and force pushing. Could I fix it somehow?

Comment: Did you check the merged commits against the criteria mentioned here: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29301361/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution